# Linearly independence and independence of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

In each part, determine whether the vectors are linearly independent
or are linearly dependent in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

(a) $(3, 8, 7,−3), (1, 5, 3,−1), (2,−1, 2, 6), (4, 2, 6, 4)$

$3k_1 + 1k_2 +2k_3 + 4k_4 = 0$

$8k_1 + 5k_2 -1k_3 + 2k_4 = 0$

$7k_1 + 3k_2 +2k_3 + 6k_4 = 0$

$-3k_1 -k_2 + 6k_3 + 4k_4 = 0$

I need to find the value of the variables $k_1, k_2, k_3$ and $k_4$.

I did use row reduction by adding first row and second row which gave me $8k_3 + 8k_4 = 0$.

But what is the next steps after that?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the determinant of the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 & 2 & 4 \\ 8 & 5 & -1 & 2 \\ 7 & 3 & 2 & 6\\ -3 & -1 & 6 & 4\\ \end{bmatrix}$. We have that $det(A) = 0$ which means the vectors above are linearly dependent.